# UWP - Writing to file from many different tasks at once

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, uwp

I recently made logging module for UWP app. It's generally speaking some static class that has asynchronous fire-and-forget method for writing some messages to file.

Because it's asynchronous I need to resolve situation in which two separate tasks will try to append text to file - it may happen on faster hardware. Is there something in UWP that will allow me to achieve such "funnel" behavior?

Comment: It is called a spooler.  Create a service that will write to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim`, see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.7.2.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about using Semaphore, but this question is more about "some kind of magical thread-safe stream that will resolve this problem automatically". Sometimes such things are already done.